# bypass websites detecting adblocker on AdGuards DNS network

Tags: dns, browser, web, adblock

I just set the AdGuards ipv4 DNS servers as the default on my router, Wifi Is now ad-free! YAY!
only one disadvantage, some websites detect this as an adblocker, and comes with the standard pop-up "please disable adblocker to continue"
is there any way I can bypass this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Disable AdGuard and allow advertisements on your network.

Seriously, that's the only way.

Many modern websites use scripts, while many of those scripts come from the domain you use, some will come from the advertisers domain. Those scripts will share a context from the webpage they run on and can effectively tell when one did or did not load.

As a result a legitimate script from the site you *are* wanting content from can detect whether a script from a site you *are not* wanting to receive content from.

That detection *might* happen in a specific lonely script or page element, but it is more likely to be embedded in a critical script set for the page.

You might, with a lot of work, be able to reverse engineer how the script detection works and disable or work around it using Greasemonkey or some other page adjustment tool, or you might even be able to remove the "please disable" element via Ublock or other adblocker in your browser, but it is trivial for the site owner to change their site to defeat you and make you go around the loop repeatedly having to work out how to block it again.

Even if it works today it could easily stop tomorrow.

But you probably won't be able to find any kind of "one size fits all" to do this for every site, at best you might be able to do it for a couple of sites at a time. There are too many methods, too many sites with different update schedules and too much effort to get their advertisements seen.

Adblockers vs Advertisers is an ongoing arms race.